# How can I unload the Process Monitor driver without restarting?

Tags: drivers, process-monitor

I sometimes use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) for debugging software, and also play games online. Some of these games use [BattlEye](https://www.battleye.com/) anti-cheat software, which refuses to allow the game to run after Process Monitor has been started on the system, showing this in the log:

```
08:06:46: Starting BattlEye Service...

08:06:49: Launching game...
08:07:07: Disallowed driver: "\??\C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\PROCMON23.SYS". Please unload it or reboot your system.
```

The driver remains loaded after closing Process Monitor, and there doesn't appear to be an option to have it unload.

Several other questions have answers about unloading drivers using `net stop` or `sc stop`, but the ProcMon driver isn't a service, so this doesn't work. I've also tried looking in Device Manager and enabling 'Show hidden devices', but none of the entries appear related to ProcMon. I can't delete the driver file, as it's not actually present on the filesystem; ProcMon stores the file in its executable and extracts it as needed.

My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1346006), which is about a similar issue where the driver persists after a reboot. My question is about unloading the driver without rebooting.

Comment: Link "this question" is broken

Comment: It seems to be impossible. So I restart and use admin cmd to delete it.

Comment: `del /ah C:\Windows\System32\drivers\PROCMON24.SYS`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Standard drivers *are* services and you can indeed control them via `net` and `sc`. (For example, take a look at `sc query beep` – stopping the 'beep' driver is a common way to shut up the internal PC speaker.)

In earlier Process Monitor versions (probably pre-2.3, when it still had Windows XP support), it would install a "legacy" device driver that *was* visible via `sc`, Device Manager, etc.

---

Current versions of Process Monitor appear to remove the driver/service configuration from registry immediately after starting the driver. You can see this by [monitoring ProcMon with itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBO6h.png). It is possible to manually re-add the service, with type 2 (kernel FS driver) and it will immediately show up as already running.

However, the service will also report "NOT_STOPPABLE" and will refuse any stop attempts.

Additionally, PROCMON23 now registers itself as a *filesystem minifilter* driver through the Filter Manager (FltDrv). You can see it in the output of `fltmc`, but attempting to externally unload it also fails (possibly because the driver doesn't have the unload routine):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fltmc

Filter Name                     Num Instances    Altitude    Frame
------------------------------  -------------  ------------  -----
PROCMON23                               0       385200         0
WdFilter                                4       328010         0
storqosflt                              0       244000         0
wcifs                                   1       189900         0
...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>fltmc unload PROCMON23

Unload failed with error: 0x801f0010
Do not detach the filter from the volume at this time.
```

Since the "official" CLI tool is unable to remove the filter from FltMgr, and FltMgr *itself* is a 'critical' driver that cannot be restarted without reboot, it would seem that there's no way to unload PROCMON23 or PROCMON24.

---

But the most interesting part: After doing the above checks with procmon 3.40, I found that the latest version on the website is 3.50 (which uses a newer PROCMON24 driver). Upon starting the new version, I was informed that an older version of the driver was already on the system and that I should reboot.

So if ProcMon *itself* cannot unload its own driver without requiring a reboot, I think you can safely assume that you won't be able to unload it either.

Comment: Given how much fruitless searching I've already done on this, this is looking more and more like the answer. However, I'm going to wait a while before accepting this, just in case someone knows of a way and happens to see this with no accepted answers and takes a look.

Comment: Is it possible to configure Windows to not load the driver when rebooting the system?

Comment: Just don't start procmon to begin with, and you are done? Check boot logging is disabled if for some reason that still isn't the case. 
Anyhow, back in topic - it seems at least for procexp [somebody](https://web.archive.org/web/20080810153241/http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=11086&PID=75831#76004) had some way to unload its driver. Too bad the thing has been lost to time.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to an [excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1346137/81203) by [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686) which concludes that there is no way to unload it, I'd like to add that normal reboot on Windows 10 does not help either, because Windows 10 nowadays persists some memory and reloads it upon boot up, so the driver ends up in memory even after reboot.

To avoid that, reboot with this command run as admin:

```
shutdown /r /f /t 0
```

which will perform proper reboot. Check by running `fltmc` as admin, that the driver is no longer there.

Comment: Thanks for adding this tip. I was surprised to see `PROCMON24` persisting even after a full shutdown & power off (upon next boot). Not until I ran your suggested `shutdown /r /f /t 0` did it not load upon next boot.

Answer (score 5):

The problematic `PROCMON23.SYS` filter driver is installed by ProcMon when it is
run. If the file
`C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\PROCMON23.SYS`
does not exist at the time, then ProcMon will write it.
The `PROCMON23.SYS` file itself is included as a binary resource inside the
executable of ProcMon.

You can list all running filter drivers by :

```
fltmc filters
```

and on my computer this gives :

[image]

As you can see, my version of Process Monitor is newer than yours (24 instead
of 23).

Usually a filter driver can be uninstalled by a command such as :

```
Fltmc unload PROCMON24
```

However, in this case this gives in an elevated Command Prompt :

[image: image2]

Unload error 0x801f0010 is the typical error for a mini-filter driver that has no unload routine.

Conclusion : PROCMON23.SYS and the later PROCMON24.SYS are badly programmed.
The developer has not foreseen that anybody would ever wish to unload his
driver and has not included the necessary routine in it.
Therefore this driver cannot be unloaded.

The bad news for you is that a reboot is required to dispose of it, nothing else
will do the job. Your only recourse is to complain to the developer.

Comment: Like closing ProcMon normally, this doesn't work. The driver is still loaded according to Battleye and NirSoft's [DriverView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html).

Comment: This closes both `Procmon.exe` and `Procmon64.exe`. It seems like you have enabled Boot logging, so undo that and reboot.

Comment: No, boot logging is not enabled. I double checked in a VM; downloading and running Process Monitor on a new system and closing it, either normally or with the /terminate flag, results in the driver not unloading.

Comment: Try this : Boot in Safe mode, uninstall Process Monitor, rename `\C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\PROCMON23.SYS` if still there then reboot. Does that get rid of it?

Comment: It also seems you are not using the latest version.

Comment: It looks like ProcMon installs `PROCMON23.SYS`. I think you should be able to use the above method to get rid of it, but it will come back again if you start ProcMon, and once it is installed it is a pain to get rid of.

Comment: A regular reboot is enough to unload the driver, as ProcMon only loads the driver it starts. However, I'm trying to find a way to unload it without rebooting.

Comment: You could replace PROCMON23.SYS by a harmless file using the above method, as probably Procmon only checks if it is present, but ProcMon will then most probably not be functional.

Comment: I have done some more research and have rewritten my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It would appear it hooks into the kernel, which you kind of need (the kernel) to keep from rebooting for other reasons (crashed PC).

[Dependency Walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhFLs.png)

This would explain why you have to reboot... it is the only way it will unhook from the kernel.