# Disallowed driver. PROCMON23.SYS

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gaming

I do not know if the question is right for this site but I will still ask.
I have a problem with one game. It is called Six Siege.

When I try to run it this window appears:
[image: error]

I found the above-mentioned driver but I do not know what to do. I tried to delete it without success.
If anyone has an idea what the cause of this problem is, I would be very grateful to him.

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1346125/how-can-i-unload-the-process-monitor-driver-without-restarting